# What is the most effective use of database or XML files?

Tags: xml, database

I'm supposed to make a choice between database and XML file for recording, reading and updating geotechnical borings which is investigation of the land with drilling.
Each boring is characterized by its coordinates (x, y), by the geological layers that compose it and with the thicknesses of each of these layers. We can imagine the borings as follows:

```
    [Boring 1
x =  155.45  
y=200.33
Layer 1 : sand -> 1m thick
Layer 2 : limestone -> 2m thick
Layer 3 : clay -> 4m thick
Layer 4 : chalk -> 2m thick
Layer 5 : gypsum -> 1m thick

Boring 2
x =  165.55  
y=166.23
Layer 1 : sand -> 1.2m thick 
Layer 2 : limestone ->2.3m thick 
Layer 3 : clay -> 3.8m thick 
Layer 4 : chalk -> 3.2m thick 
Layer 5 : gypsum -> 1.3m thick 

Boring 3
x =  140.67  
y=203.65
Layer 1 : sand -> 0.8m thick 
Layer 2 : limestone ->2.7m thick 
Layer 3 : clay -> 4.2m thick 
Layer 4 : chalk -> 1.2m thick 
Layer 5 : gypsum -> 1m thick 

    Boring 4
    x =  130.45  
    y=209.22
    Layer 1 : sand -> 1m thick 
    Layer 2 : limestone ->2m thick 
    Layer 3 : clay -> 4m thick 
    Layer 4 : chalk -> 2m thick 
    Layer 5 : gypsum -> 1m thick][1]
```

Knowing that in reality, we have thousands of geotechnical borings and that we use an ACCESS database, so I wonder what is the most effective, reliable and fast the using of ACCESS database or XML file.
Thanks.

Comment: The data seems very simple and the quantity seems very modest (i.e., thousands rather than millions). You haven't said anything about the number of users or transaction rates. If you're currently using an Access database, why are you considering a change? Does it meet your requirements, or not?

Comment: the number of user is just one. actually we use access databsae

Comment: Then what motivates you to consider a change? What would you hope to achieve from the XML approach that you cannot get from the existing approach?